# How can I retry HTTP client requests within a HttpClientFilter using Micronaut?

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client

I've implemented a micronaut `HttpClientFilter` to add a cached bearer token for all requests to a 3rd party service, however this token expires fairly regularly. I would like to reauthenticate with the downstream API and retry the request when this happens, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do this. So far I'm simply calling `proceed` a second time, however this causes an `Index out of bounds` error to be thrown (I *think* that [this](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/6217dba131b81ec99f4e0bf6ef542369c0c3b73f/http-client/src/main/java/io/micronaut/http/client/DefaultHttpClient.java#L1991) is the exception that is *supposed* to be thrown, but there appears to be a bug in Micronaut here). Minimal reduction of what I've got is below:

```
import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.HttpStatus;
import io.micronaut.http.MutableHttpRequest;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Filter;
import io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException;
import io.micronaut.http.filter.ClientFilterChain;
import io.micronaut.http.filter.HttpClientFilter;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;

import javax.inject.Inject;

interface AuthTokenProvider {
    // cached
    Flowable<String> fetchToken();
    void invalidateToken();
}

@Filter(serviceId = "third-party-api")
public class AuthTokenFilter implements HttpClientFilter {
    @Inject AuthTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private Flowable<HttpResponse<?>> buildRequestWithToken(MutableHttpRequest<?> request, ClientFilterChain chain) {
        return tokenProvider.fetchToken()
                .map(token -> request.bearerAuth(token))
                .flatMap(chain::proceed);
    }

    @Override
    public Flowable<HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(MutableHttpRequest<?> request, ClientFilterChain chain) {
        return buildRequestWithToken(request, chain)
                .onErrorResumeNext(err -> {
                    System.out.println("API request failed, invalidating token and retrying");

                    tokenProvider.invalidateToken();
                    return buildRequestWithToken(request, chain);
                });
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest the correct way to do this?

Comment: ATM it looks like retrying is not possible through a filter

Comment: In case you'd use the declarative clients (in case thats possible for you) they offer a CircuitBreaker with a retry option, check the docs under 7.3.6 Retry and Circuit Breaker.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use advanced-expiration property in application.yml If you set it to 200secs then micronaut considers the token expired 200sec before the actual expiry period. https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/#io.micronaut.security.oauth2.configuration.OauthClientConfigurationProperties$ClientCredentialsConfigurationProperties
2. You can use retry annotation provided by micronaut in 18th page in this deck https://objectcomputing.com/files/6315/7297/3014/Slide_Deck_Micronaut_Declarative_HTTP_Client_Webinar.pdf